# Does a convergent sequence imply separated?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let (X,d) be a metric space. Prove that $A, B\subseteq$ X are not separated iff there exists a convergent sequence $x_{n}$ $\rightarrow$x with either x $\in$ B and $x_{n}$ $\in$ A for all n, or x $\in$ A and $x_{n}$ $\in$ B for all n.

I initially attempted this problem by breaking into a bunch of cases regarding whether are an arbitrary element in the intersection was in both A and B, but the finished proof didn't look right. I made a sketch in R2 and wasn't sure if the ideas generalized to an arbitrary metric space. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming by separated you mean that there exists $\delta>0$, such $d(a,b)>\delta$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$?

Comment: By the way, did you manage any direction of the problem?

Comment: To me separated is that $\overline{A} \cap B$  = $\overline{B} \cap A$  = $\emptyset$ and I applied that to this problem

Comment: Well I haven't read all the answers yet but your iff statement is if P then Q and if Q then P so you could say that if $A,B$ are separated in a space then both $x_n$ and $x$ $\in$ A or B (I am guessing the vice-versa will be the way to go but the iff condition holds here too)

Answer (score 1):

The core idea of the proof here is that of closure: if $\{x_n\}_{n \in {\mathbb N}}$ converges to $x$ in $A$ then $x\in \bar{A}$ and so if $x\in B$ also then $\bar{A}\cap B \not= \emptyset$.  You might want to stop reading here and see if you can complete the proof yourself with that in mind :)

Making the idea above explicit however: suppose that $\{x_n\}_{n \in {\mathbb N}} \rightarrow x$ where $x_n \in A \ \forall \ n \in {\mathbb N}$ and $x\in B$ and suppose that $\bar{A} \cap B = \emptyset$.  Then, because that intersection in empty and we are in a metric space, we can find some $\eta > 0$ such that $d(x_n, x) > \eta \ \forall \ n\in {\mathbb N}$.  However, because $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence, we can also find $N\in {\mathbb N}$ and $\varepsilon_N >0$ (the subscript indicates the dependence on $N$) so that $d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon _N \ \forall \ n > N$.  Now take $\varepsilon _N = \eta / 2$ and we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Well you would need to say what $\overline{A}$ is for example. A Characterization of $\overline{A}$ in a metric space, is the set of points $x\in X$ such that $d(a_n,x)\to0$ for some sequence $\{ a_n \}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq A$.

If you are okay with this, then $\overline{A}\cap B\neq \emptyset$ means exactly that there exists $x\in B$ and a sequence $d(a_n,x)\to 0$, with $\{ a_n \}\subseteq A$. Similarly for $\overline{B}\cap A\neq \emptyset$.